# How do I call images from xcassets?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality

How can I call an image that I have saved in the xcassets folder?

I'm using ARKit. I'd like to make an "Earth" figure by wrapping an "Earth" skin around a spherical node. I can assign a color to it, like so:

```
earth.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blue
```

But I'm unable to assign textures using either:

```
earth.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = "#imageLiteral(resourceName:8k_earth_daymap)
```

or

```
earth.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named:"8k_earth_daymap.jpg")
```

Am I using the wrong commands? It seems like Xcode does not recognize the 8k_earth_daymap.jpg file I have saved locally in xcassets...

Comment: Are you sure your image is named `8k_earth_daymap.jpg`? Is it throwing a compile error or run time error? Can you share the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

`earth.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = "#imageLiteral(resourceName:8k_earth_daymap)` is not real code; there is an extra quotation mark, so this wouldn't compile.

`earth.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named:"8k_earth_daymap.jpg")` is wrong, because `.jpg` would not be part of the name of an image set.

Finally, the phrase "that I have saved in the xcassets folder" is worrisome. You must not put *anything* manually into the xcassets folder. You must let Xcode do that. You simply edit the asset catalog in the project navigator and work by way of Xcode's asset catalog editor window. If you're not working through this window, you're doing it wrong:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, @matt. Your suggestion helped. I was adding the jpg extension when it was not needed. I was also calling the image using an Image Literal, but for some reason, it did not work. I was able to call the image using UIImage.